# What is the procedure into showing codewords are a perfect block code?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

Suppose that I had 2 given codewords i.e. 000 and 111.

I want to show that this is a perfect block code (or at least check).

Could anyone please outline the process of what I would do.

Thanks

Comment: Start by stating the **definition** of "perfect binary code"!

Comment: What do you mean by a perfect binary code?

Comment: Apologies I meant to say block code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfect $1$-error correcting because the (closed) Hamming-balls of radius $1$ around the codewords partition the total message space:

The $1$-ball around $000$ is $\{000,001,010,100\}$ and the $1$-ball around $111$ is  $\{111, 110, 101,011\}$, which are disjoint and cover $\{0,1\}^3$

Comment: Thank you for your help.